# Shadows not showing when the distance increase b/w trees and Camera in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, shadow, light

Trees are placed randomly every time on plane at runtime and camera moving forward continuously at z axis and static on other axis , actually the problem is that when camera position more than 10 on y axis the shadow not displaying but when the value is equal to 10 or less works fine but when move up more than 10 on y axis the shadows are not displaying.i increase the value of shadow distance in quality settings(eg.shadow distance=1000) but nothing effects.one more thing everything things work fine in unity.But not work on android device.[image]

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution of problem.Actually i was doing wrong that is selecting the fantastic while building my game for android.the right selection was simple because the green tick for android in that Row.After tweaking the quality settings will effect on android build.....[image]